# New profile page layout and the helpful flags page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, profile-page

Apologies if this is already something that has been mentioned (I had a quick look and didn't see anything). The new profile page looks nice but the switch between the various pages within your profile and the "helpful flags" page is a little jarring as the helpful flags page hasn't been updated with the new header from the profile page. This means that while you can navigate around the new profile page with the various links for each section, once you head into helpful flags you have to do something different to get back (ie: click your profile link or click the back button).

I am presuming that this isn't by design and the helpful flags page hasn't been updated yet, but just in case - it would be nice if this page followed the same look, feel and layout of the rest of the new profile page if possible?

Comment: I received a message upon opening the flag dialog today that said "some of your recent flags have been declined, please review them..." Clicked through from page one, all the way to page 15 where I was finally able to find my most recent declined flag. LOL

Answer (score 3):

I totally agree. I always found that link a little odd.

Why not create a `flags` tab, next to `votes`? Like this:

[image: flags tab]

Comment: Well, I kinda like the new link in the side bar, it's just once you click it, the side bar, the profile menu bar, and everything else just vanishes, leaving you feeling like you've just left your profile page